# During bumblebee install, bumblebee and nvidia-libgl are in conflict. Should I remove nvidia-libgl?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to get Bumblebee up and running on an Acer Aspire V3-572G-55FT laptop. So far I've installed xorg-server, xorg-xinit, xorg-utils, xorg-server-utils, mesa, xorg-twm, xterm, xorg-xclock, and all required dependencies. When installing mesa for the first time, I opted to install nvidia-libgl instead of mesa-libgl. I'm now, as per the Arch wiki, running the following command:

```
sudo pacman -S mesa xf86-video-intel bumblebee nvidia bbswitch primus mesa-demos
```

I get the following output:

```
:: bumblebee and nvidia-libgl are in conflict. Remove nvidia-libgl? [y/N]
```

What's the correct course of action to take here? Am I doing the right thing so far? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's problem in nvidia-utils (nvidia-libgl is part of it) conflicting with bumblebee. I found the solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138913). You should install `nvidia-bumblebee` package instead of `nvidia`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is on reddit, and I'm repeating it here:

> It's fine. Remove nvidia-libgl.
>
> If you pacman -Si bumblebee, notice that it provides nvidia-ligbl. That means that it covers the dependency for other packages that require nvidia-libgl.

by LazinCajun. [Permalink](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/2sh4oq/bumblebee_and_nvidialibgl_are_in_conflict_should/cnpkbm7)